# How to change date and time format for datepicker in web2py

Tags: datetime, datepicker, web2py

I want to quickly change the ouput format of web2py´s datepicker used in `datetime` or `date` fields in forms - or completely disable it. Where can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the file ´web2py_ajax.html´

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    // These variables are used by the web2py_ajax_init function in web2py_ajax.js (which is loaded below).
    var w2p_ajax_confirm_message = "{{=T('Are you sure you want to delete this object?')}}";
    var w2p_ajax_disable_with_message = "{{=T('Working...')}}";
    var w2p_ajax_date_format = "{{=T('%d.%m.%Y')}}";
    var w2p_ajax_datetime_format = "{{=T('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}}";
    var ajax_error_500 = '{{=T.M('An error occured, please [[reload %s]] the page') % URL(args=request.args, vars=request.get_vars) }}'
    //--></script>
{{
response.files.insert(0,URL('static','js/jquery.js'))
response.files.insert(1,URL('static','css/calendar.css'))
response.files.insert(2,URL('static','js/calendar.js'))
response.files.insert(3,URL('static','js/web2py.js'))
response.include_meta()
response.include_files()
}}
```

Change var `w2p_ajax_date_format` for a different date format or edit the response.files-lines.